# HTML table design issue with 22 column in row with menu collapse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have one table shown on the screen with a menu layout.
While the menu is not collapsed the table is showing perfectly on screen like the below image.

[image]

But once I collapse the menu toggle button, the table design is getting out of the screen like the below image. The last three columns were out of the screen body.

[image]

Below is the code for table I am using.

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" bordercolor="#999999">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="24" width="20%">Customer</td>
            <td width="15%">Purchase</td>
            <td width="15%">Branch</td>
            <td width="15%">Status</td>
            <td width="15%">PO Issue date</td>
            <td width="15%">Delivery Date</td>
            <td width="15%">Return Date</td>
            <td width="15%">Approved By</td>
            <td width="15%">Equipment Recovery</td>
            <td width="15%">Labor Recovery</td>
            <td width="15%">Shipping Recovery</td>
            <td width="15%">Purchase Recovery</td>
            <td width="15%">Other Recovery</td>
            <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td>Equipment Rental</td>
            <td>Labor</td>
            <td>Shipping</td>
            <td>Equipment Purchase</td>
            <td>Other</td>
            <td>Tax</td>
            <td>Loss Code</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" width="100%">Internal Notes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td height="24" colspan="13">
                <div align="right"><strong>TOTALS</strong></div>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#E6E6E6">$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td>$0.00</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I overcome it?

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @lost_in_magento I want a Responsive Table design.
if I had collapsed menu (left menu with collapse functionality you can see it in two different image above given) or not. the table should display perfectly without going out screen.

Comment: It will go out of the viewport. Since there is no space inside the container!

Comment: @lost_in_magentoOkay fine!!! Is that any alternative option ?